# How to extract DB name and table name from a comma separated string of Dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe column `table_name` which is having below string value:

```
tradingpartner.parent_supplier,lookup.store,lab_promo_invoice.tl_cc_mbr_prc_wkly_inv,lab_promo_invoice.mpp_club_card_promotion_funding_view,lab_promo_invoice.supplier_sale_apportionment_cc,tradingpartner.supplier,stores.rpm_zone_location_mapping,lookup.calendar
```

How to extract DB name and table name from the above string and store it as `DB name` in one column and `tablename` in another column.

I want the output as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to define two different UDF to achieve the goal.

Starting from this input DataFrame, called `dfInput`:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|table_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|tradingpartner.parent_supplier,lookup.store,lab_promo_invoice.tl_cc_mbr_prc_wkly_inv,lab_promo_invoice.mpp_club_card_promotion_funding_view,lab_promo_invoice.supplier_sale_apportionment_cc,tradingpartner.supplier,stores.rpm_zone_location_mapping,lookup.calendar,sauces,plant|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The  first UDF, called `dbName`, is responsible to take from the input String column all the database names from the String:

```
def dbNames(k: String): String = {

  // this String is the returning value 
  // containing all the databases from the input string
  var dbNames=""

  // split the input String by comma
  val arrays = k.split(",")
  for (str <- arrays){

    // if in the input String there is a value like
    // database.table take just the database value
    if(str.contains(".")) {
      val indexOfPoint = str.indexOf(".")
      dbNames += str.substring(0, indexOfPoint) + ", "
    }
  }
  // delete last occurence of char ", "
  return dbNames.dropRight(2)
}
val dbName = udf[String, String](dbNames)
```

The  second UDF, called `tableName`, is responsible to take from the input String column all the table names from the String:

```
def tableNames(k: String): String = {

  // this String is the returning value 
  // containing all the tables from the input string
  var tableNames=""

  // split the input String by comma
  val arrays = k.split(",")
  for (str <- arrays){

    // if in the input String there is a value like
    // database.table take just the table value
    // else is intended to be just the table name
    if(str.contains(".")) {
      val indexOfPoint = str.indexOf(".")
      tableNames += str.substring(indexOfPoint+1) + ", "
    }
    else tableNames += str + ", "
  }
  // delete last occurence of char ", "
  return tableNames.dropRight(2)
}
val tableName = udf[String, String](tableNames)
```

Then, to obtain the expected output we need to call the UDFs like the following:

```
val dfOutput = dfInput.withColumn("DBName", dbName(col("table_name")))
                      .withColumn("Table", tableName(col("table_name")))
dfOutput.show(true)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|table_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |DBName                                                                                                         |Table                                                                                                                                                                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|tradingpartner.parent_supplier,lookup.store,lab_promo_invoice.tl_cc_mbr_prc_wkly_inv,lab_promo_invoice.mpp_club_card_promotion_funding_view,lab_promo_invoice.supplier_sale_apportionment_cc,tradingpartner.supplier,stores.rpm_zone_location_mapping,lookup.calendar,sauces,plant|tradingpartner, lookup, lab_promo_invoice, lab_promo_invoice, lab_promo_invoice, tradingpartner, stores, lookup|parent_supplier, store, tl_cc_mbr_prc_wkly_inv, mpp_club_card_promotion_funding_view, supplier_sale_apportionment_cc, supplier, rpm_zone_location_mapping, calendar, sauces, plant|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```